# Does selenium webdriver supports sending text to iframe in browsers other than Firefox? I am facing issue in IE and Chrome

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, iframe, automation, webdriver

```
Driver.driver.switchTo().frame("iframe-user-text-input-div")
      .findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/font")).sendKeys("dummytext");
Driver.driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

The above code works perfectly in Firefox but gives exception in IE (element not accessible) and chrome(element not found) .

Does Selenium Webdriver supports iframes in IE 10 and chrome 31.0.1650.48 m?

Answer (score 0):

Used the below code to access iframe in chrome and it worked-

```
WebElement t = Driver.driver.findElement(By.id("iframe-user-text-input-div")); 
Driver.driver.switchTo().frame(t);
Driver.driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/font")).click();
Driver.driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body")).sendKeys(randomtext);
Driver.driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

But still have issues with IE.